# Is it possible to use/interact with Deno scripts from within a NodeJS application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deno, nrwl-nx

I'm interested in Deno, and I was curious about trying it in an NX application that would provide some scripting for an existing library. This existing `library` is a library of reusable React components and it's a NodeJS project with a package.json.

That said, my `library` is within a lib in an NX monorepo (which has it's own package.json, etc), and I wonder if the Deno scripts could also live within an NX lib.

I'm just trying to wrap my head around all of this, as I'm relatively new to Node, NX, and Deno.

I know Deno isn't meant to be used within a pre-existing Node application - it's a separate run time, but I just want to call the Deno scripts from a separate library, so it seems it would be possible?

One thing I don't really understand about a strictly Deno application is how you ship around something like that? Or is the point that you usually are just installing it on a server, as it's more intended for that use case than as a way to manage dependencies in a front-end application?

I found this package: https://github.com/kt3k/deno-bin which sort seems on the right track. Perhaps I could use this to create a dependency for the Deno executable. Then when I ship my monorepo, I have Deno as a dependency in the package.json which will allow the front-end library access to the CLI in order to call scripts in my `scripts` library.

I'd love if someone can help me understand what I don't here.

Comment: Node and Deno will NOT be in the same process since they are completely different runtimes.  So, any communication between them will have to be two separate apps using some form of interprocess communication to communicate.

Comment: There has been work towards Node compatibility in Deno. Here are some entrypoints for research: https://deno.com/blog/v1.15#improving-node-compatibility -- https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/2644 -- https://deno.land/std@0.112.0/node/README.md